# how to convert Some(ArrayBuffer("myString", "String")) to List of string

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a method that return `Some(ArrayBuffer("myString", "String"))` after using `.map()` method, how can I convert it to a list of string?

Thats how it looks like right now, I'm wondering if I can use flatMap instead of map?

```
res.featureList.asScala
      .get("Whitelist")
      .map(
        feature =>
          feature.whitelistedIdWithReasons.asScala
            .map(f => f.accountIdRuleName)
      ).toList.flatten
```

Comment: `.get.toList` but that's only good if it's always `Some()` and never `None`. Not a safe bet.

Comment: @jwvh why not `map`ping it and then `get`?

Comment: @Andronicus; Sure. Either way works, except it's still not safe.

Comment: @jwvh why not? If I define `val b: Option[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]] = None`, then `b.map(_.toList)` results in `Option[List[String]] = None`

Comment: @Andronicus; The `.map()` is fine. It's the `.get` part that's unsafe. Place it first or last, makes no difference. It shouldn't be there. A better way to unwrap an `Option` is via pattern-matching. (I also think `.fold()` is a pretty good "option" as well.)

Comment: @jay; You've added code that appears to be totally unrelated to the original question. Post a new question instead complicating an already answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` it further:

```
Some(ArrayBuffer("myString", "String"))
    .map(_.toList)
    .get
```

Instead of `get` you can use `orElse` to provide a default value and avoid exception thrown.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Some(ArrayBuffer("myString", "String")).toList.flatten
```

First turn the `Option[ArrayBuffer[String]]` into a `List[ArrayBuffer[String]]`. Then flatten the `List[ArrayBuffer[String]]` into a `List[String]`

Comment: Cute, but you can save a step: `...toList.flatMap(_.toList)`

Comment: @jwvh Why use a flatmap when you can just flatten it? There is no need to map the ArrayBuffer to a List, since it is iterable. (Note: I've edited my answer after jwvh's comment)

Comment: Hmm, no `map()` needed at all. Good catch.

Comment: @tillaert Hi, I made edit of my question, can I use flatMap in this case?

Comment: @jay I can't tell, I don't know what the types are. But can you do the ```.toList``` before the ```.map(...)```? Then you can replace the ```.map(...).flatten``` with ```.flatMap(...)```

Answer (score 0):

```
Some(ArrayBuffer("myString", "String")).fold(List.empty[String])(_.toList)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.